# Popover Segue Crashes When Called Programmatically

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am using XCode 4.2 storyboards.
Originally I had a Popover Segue anchored to a UIButton on a UIViewController embedded in a Navigational controller and all was well.

Now I need to add conditional behavior before performing the segue so I did the following:

- Deleted the segue
- Created a new segue from the UIViewController
- Created an IBAction from the button
- Called `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self]` in the IBAction

The app gets through prepareForSegue but then it throws a SIGABRT and logs the following

```
 \*** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue perform], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UIStoryboardPopoverSegue.m:27
```

Any ideas? I have other instances of this working fine with push segues. Is this a case of misbehaving popovers that I keep on hearing reference to?

Comment: Did you give the segue an identifer (name)?

Comment: Yup. It's getting to prepareForSegue successfully :(

Comment: Did you solve it? Did you set the anchor?

Comment: Did not solve it. Had to build a custom segue as workaround. I tried the same scenario from scratch and got the same problem. What do you mean by set the anchor? The point was that I needed to remove the anchor in order to have conditional behavior.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the specific issue at hand but [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self] must be called after the view is initialised otherwise it will give you a similar exception

Answer (score 10):

Maybe it's a bit late:

The anchor defines the starting point of the popover that you want to show and is not connected to an action. It must be set.

So when you want to call the popover segue programmatically, you have to do it in two steps:

**1. Connect the Segue to the ViewController** You simply drag from your ViewController that should perform the segue to the destination ViewController and select Popover.

[image: Connect Segue to ViewController]

**2. Define the identifier** This is necessary to call perform the segue from your code

**3. Connect the Anchor** You drag the anchor to the Object from which you want the popover to start from. In the image below it's a BarButtonItem. Note: this does not automatically perform the segue! (This way you can additionally perform some actions connecting to the BarButtonItem)

[image: Connect the Anchor]

**4. Call the segue from your code**

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier" sender:sender];
```